# Botframework V4: Python Cosmos DB config

Tags: python, botframework

I am currently trying to use CosmosDB as state storage but encountering some issues when the bot attempts to save the state in CosmosDB.

Below is the code that I am using CosmosDB as the middleware

```
LOOP = asyncio.get_event_loop()
APP = Flask(__name__)
APP.config.update(VaultConfig.get_config())
APP.wsgi_app = BotTelemetryMiddleware(APP.wsgi_app)
PORT = APP.config["Settings"]["Port"]
INSTRUMENTATION_KEY = APP.config['Settings']["appinsight_instrumentation_key"]
TELEMETRY_CLIENT = ApplicationInsightsTelemetryClient(INSTRUMENTATION_KEY)
SETTINGS = BotFrameworkAdapterSettings(
    APP.config["Settings"]["AppId"], APP.config["Settings"]["AppPassword"]
)

cosmos_config = APP.config['COSMOS']
# Create CosmosStorage and ConversationState
cosmos = CosmosDbStorage(CosmosDbConfig(endpoint=cosmos_config['endpoint'], masterkey=cosmos_config['masterKey'],
                                         database=cosmos_config['database'], container=cosmos_config['container'], partition_key='/id'))
# Create MemoryStorage, UserState and ConversationState


USER_STATE = UserState(cosmos)
CONVERSATION_STATE = ConversationState(cosmos)
ADAPTER = BotFrameworkAdapter(SETTINGS)
ADAPTER.on_turn_error = on_error
```

The error that I am receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bot/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_adapter.py", line 95, in run_pipeline
    context, callback
  File "/bot/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 69, in receive_activity_with_status
    return await self.receive_activity_internal(context, callback)
  File "/bot/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 79, in receive_activity_internal
    return await callback(context)
  File "/bot/main.py", line 146, in aux_func
    await BOT.on_turn(turn_context)
  File "/bot/bots/dialog_bot.py", line 46, in on_turn
    await self.conversation_state.save_changes(turn_context, False)
  File "/bot/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_state.py", line 88, in save_changes
    await self._storage.write(changes)
  File "/bot/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botbuilder/azure/cosmosdb_storage.py", line 196, in write
    raise error
  File "/bot/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botbuilder/azure/cosmosdb_storage.py", line 168, in write
    e_tag = change.e_tag
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'e_tag'
```

Attempting to modify this file /bot/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botbuilder/azure/cosmosdb_storage.py for a temporary patch seems to lead me down a rabbit hole that makes it seems like CosmosDB is not fully implemented/tested to be used yet. Am I doing this right?

There were no current samples to work with.

Comment: Also to note that I have attempted to use CosmosDB Emulator and Azure CosmosDB. I have also let the bot create the DB/Container as well, but I believe the issues lie within the Middleware

Comment: Were you able to get it working by modifying the module? What changes did you make?

Comment: Hi Kyle, I had little understanding of how state was being stored and how it was being used as middleware. The code previously always had a hard assumption that  .etag will be an attribute of the state we are trying to save. Modify my way around it by checking if etag does not exist, set it to None. This is solved now with the commit  axelsrz put in https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python/commit/843edfc1f4c563d58ba639b23f2bb019bdbc381b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CosmosDB has been fixed with the following commit: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python/commit/843edfc1f4c563d58ba639b23f2bb019bdbc381b